# Can I apply a regex to file filter on Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a folder full of xml files, and I want to search through them for a particular ID.

However, I only want to search the files that are of the format hello_apple_01.xml, hello_apple_02.xml... and not hello_banana_01.xml.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I don't think notepad++ can use a regex to open files, but you can create a script using the regex to open the matching files in notepad++ and then search for the text.

Comment: You could always just Find in Files, filtering by `hello_apple_*.xml`.